# Display matlab's program's output calling for another c++ program

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm not sure if my question is clear:

I have a C++ project that I run from Qtcreator, this program call another c++ script outside the project. This last one runs a shell script calling a bunch of matlab scripts.

I want to display output from the matlab scripts, `disp` doesn't work.
 I tried to write the values I want to read in a .txt file. The file is created but stay empty.
I tried these lines to write in a file:

```
fileId= fopen('imagename.txt','a');
fprintf(fileId, 'test : %s',imageName);
fclose(fileId);
```

I also tried `assignin` with the values I want to show but they're not kept within matlab's workspace.

I can't change the architecture of the whole program because it's a big project made by someone else I have to continue.

Do you have another way to watch what is going on the matlab scripts?
It's difficult to launch them directly from Matlab as I don't have access to their inputs values. I can hardly change the c++ script calling them to display theses values because I have a 'reference to ofstream is ambiguous' issue when I try to build it, so I will have to debug something made by someone else and non commented.

Comment: If this is C++, your `fprintf` requires the print format specifier in **double quotes** ("), e.g. "test : %s".  Check your favorite reference for "printf format"

Comment: I used the `fprintf` in the matlab scripts because every variables I want to check are here, so I guess the simple quotes (') used are correct?

Comment: In C++, the [fprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) function requires a text string for its formatting.  A text string can be a literal string (using double quotes) or a pointer to a character array.  In C and C++, the single quote is used for single character literals.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm not using C++ `fprintf` function, I'm using the Matlab's `fprintf`. The C++ code is here to call Matlabs' scripts, so within the Matlab's script I try to display values using `fprintf`. I even tried to use double-quotes (") in the `fprintf` but Matlab doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the file you write to stays empty is weird and I would try to find the reason regardless of your question.
Anyway, since you call Matlab from a shell script I guess you use 'matlab -r' option with your script name, or something similar. In that case you can use the `-f` option which tells Matlab to write the command line output to a log file:

```
matlab -logfile output.log
```

Comment: I agree, I also would like to know why my .txt stays empty.
I think it's because of the variable I want to display. Because when I try to only write a mere string like 'test', it's written in my file, but as soon as I want to concatenate my variable **imageName**, it doesn't work.
However **imageName** is supposed to be a string as I call the matlab function from a bash script so I don't know where is the issue.
I guess I will see it using the `-logfile` function, thanks for the tips by the way.